# Is there any Hibernate MultiTableBulkIdStrategy not doing any DDL?

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate handles UPDATE and DELETE operations on tables that are joined by the JOINED inheritance strategy by storing the IDs of updated or deleted records in a temporary or persistent table ([an excellent blog post about this](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/MultitableBulkOperations)).

Hibernate provides three different implementations for this:

1. `GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy` - Strategy based on ANSI SQL's definition of a "global temporary table"
2. `LocalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy` - Strategy based on ANSI SQL's definition of a "local temporary table" (local to each db session)
3. `PersistentTableBulkIdStrategy` - Strategy that mimics global temporary tables for databases which do not support temporary tables

The problem is that we have a constraint that we cannot execute any DDL from the application (creating any tables beforehand is no problem).

We expect very few updates/deletes that would utilize the strategy (operating on small amount of rows), so performance is not a problem. We also use the same ID type for all entities (UUID).

I see two acceptable approaches:

1. *Use single pre-created table*
   As we can create the required tables beforehand, we could in theory use one of default strategies. However as all of the standard strategies create a table per each entity in hierarchy, this leads to extra manual work each time a new one is added.
   To avoid that, I think a single table holding a pair of (`HT_TABLE_NAME`, `ID`) could be used, where `HT_TABLE_NAME` is added to segment rows for different entities (basically, merging all the temp tables into one).
2. *Store IDs in application memory*
   A strategy could fetch the IDs to the application and then send them back to the database with each update/delete statement.

I was a little surprised there is no strategy like that provided by Hibernate out-of-the-box, but maybe you know one that would work?

I also managed to find [an implementation based on Common Table Expressions](https://github.com/epiresdasilva/cte-multi-table-bulk-id-stategy), but looking at its test suite it does not look very mature. Has anyone used that with success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have developed a [`SingleGlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy`](https://github.com/grimsa/hibernate-single-table-bulk-id-strategy) that uses a single pre-created global temporary table.

Also FYI, the CTE strategy linked in the original question did not generate valid SQL for both H2 and DB2 databases.

**Update**: Hibernate 5.2.8 added [new Bulk Id strategies](http://in.relation.to/2017/02/01/non-temporary-table-bulk-id-strategies/), which made my project obselete for most cases.